# Equivalence relation R is $|R|\geq n+2$

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science, equivalence-relations

I have been asked to proove this following statement:

If a given equivalence relation $R$ on $A=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ has less than $n$ equivalence classes, then $|R|\geq n+2$

Comment: Think about it this way, reflexivity already gives you $n$ members in $R$. In which case are these are the only $n$ members?

Comment: For an alternate approach, recognize that every equivalence relation can be described having started with the identity relation and "melding together" certain equivalence classes to make a [*"finer"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_topologies) equivalence relation.  Doing so can only increase the number of pairs.  All that remains is recalling that $(x+y)^2 = x^2+\color{red}{2xy}+y^2$ so having melded together an equivalence class of size $x$ and of size $y$ into one of size $x+y$ will have increased the number of relations in the equivalence relation by $2xy$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove the claim it suffices to show that there exists at least one equivalence class with two or more elements. That's true because if there are two elements $m,k \in A$ such that $m \neq k$ and $mRk$ then by reflexivity $kRm$ holds which combined by the fact that $pRp$ for every $p \in A$ gives us that $|R| \geq n+2$. Now let's prove that this is indeed the case. Suppose that for every $m,k \in A$ with $m\neq k$ we have $(m,k) \not\in R$. Then we would have exactly one equivalence class for each element of $A$ so we would have exactly $n$ equivalence classes, which is a contradiction. Therefore, there exists at least one equivalence class with two or more elements.

Comment: Try not to answer questions when someone dumps one here, like the above, with no effort. It is more helpful to get them to do some work themselves (which is why people often ask "what have you tried?"). Also, it is not unlikely that this is their assessed homework, so giving them the complete answer is a kick in the teeth to the rest of their class.